# How to design a fast moving tilt table capable of lifting and holding 35kg/75lb?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, power, linear-motion, linear-motors

I have a rectangular table about 0.5m(20") x 1m(40"). I need to lift one end of it, similar to a tilting table using something like a linear actuator (think CNC Z-axis).

The load is fairly heavy and need to move quickly: I need it to lift 35kg(~75lb) across a 250mm(~10in) stroke at a fast rate (150mm(~6in) per sec) and hold it indefinitely without supplying power (e.g. using a brake).

I was looking at C-Beam Linear Actuators with NEMA 23 steppers and 16/5mm ball-screw, but I don't know if that's powerful enough or able to hold a load without power. An encoder would be great to have as well but I can work with end-stops.

Space is constricted, so I can't have much extra railing or anything.

Any recommendations / or feedback on how I could proceed?

Here's a quick diagram:
[image: tilt table design]